# Passing temporary struct as template argument

Tags: c++, templates, struct

I'm in the process of creating a vector class and am trying to figure out ways to reuse the maximum amount of code for different size vectors.
Here's a basic example:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D>
class Vector
{
public:
    union {
        T v[D];
        struct {
            /* T x;
             * T y;
             * T z;
             * T w;
             */
        };
    };

    Vector()
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<D; ++i)
            (*this)[i] = T(0);
    }
    Vector(T scalar)
    {
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<D; ++i)
            (*this)[i] = scalar;
    }

    inline T operator[](int i) { return (*this).v[i]; }
};
```

I want the member variables to be publicly accessible. Ex:

```
Vector<float,2> vec;
printf("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f\n", vec.x, vec.y);
```

What I'd like to do is something along the lines of this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2 : public Vector<T,2, struct { T x; T y; }> {};

template<typename T>
class Vector3 : public Vector<T,2, struct { T x; T y; T z; }> {};
```

and have it override a struct in the union:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D, struct C>
class Vector
{
public:
    union {
        T v[D];
        // Place the passed struct here
    };
};
```

Is there any feasible way to do this? I do not want to use anything other than the standard library if possible. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** After reading upon all of the answers, I have understood that the way I am using unions is incorrect! Thank you to @M.M for pointing this out. I have since chosen to go a different route, but I have selected the answer that best fit what I was looking for at the time. Once again, thank you for all of the welcomed responses below!

Comment: Do you actually *want* to pass the struct in to `Vector` or do you just want a way to define Vector2/3/4 that produces the final result? This class doesn't seem like it would be very useful for sizes > 6-8. Also you don't want `T(0)` in your ctor, you want `T{}` to default initialize it.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're doing, but bear in mind that in C++ only the most recently-assigned member of a union may be read; e.g. it is not permitted to write to `v` then read from `x`.

Comment: What @MM said is really important! Don't use `union` to "convert" a value to another. Take a look at `std::tuple` and overload of `operator[]` to achieve what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly your main purpose was to to declare order of fields that corresponds to the array elements of templated class. You cannot do this directly as templates does not accept inline type as parameter. To workaround the problem you could play with non-type template parameters to bind some labels to given index of an array:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

struct Label { } x, y, z, w;

template <Label&... labels>
struct Pack { };

template <class, class>
struct VectorParent;

template <Label&... labels, size_t... Is>
struct VectorParent<Pack<labels...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> {
   static std::unordered_map<Label *, size_t> label_map;
};

template <Label&... labels, size_t... Is>
std::unordered_map<Label *, size_t> VectorParent<Pack<labels...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::label_map = {{&labels, Is}...};

struct LabelNotFound { };

template <class T, size_t N, Label&... labels>
struct Vector:VectorParent<Pack<labels...>, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(labels)>> {
   static_assert(N == sizeof...(labels),
       "the cound of labels should corespond to the number of elements of the vector");
   using VectorParent<Pack<labels...>, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(labels)>>::label_map;
   T t[N];
   T &operator->*(Label& l) {
      auto it = label_map.find(&l);
      if (it == label_map.end())
         throw LabelNotFound{};
      return t[it->second];
   }
};

int main() {
    Vector<float,2,x,y> vec;
    vec->*x = 10.0f;
    printf("X: %.2f, Y: %.2f\n", vec->*x, vec->*y); // prints: X: 10.00, Y: 0.00
    //vec->*w = 10.1f; //would throw an exception LabelNotFound
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are trying to do is not allowed.
Anyway, you can do this:

```
template<typename T>
struct S { T x; T y; };

template<typename T>
class Vector2 : public Vector<T,2,S<T>> {};
```

Or this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector2 : public Vector<T,2,S> {};
```

In the second case, `Vector` can be defined as:

```
template<typename T, unsigned int D, template<typename> class S>
class Vector {
    using MyStruct = S<T>;

    // ...

    union {
        T v[D];
        MyStruct myStruct;
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is a non-class type?  What do non-type template-parameters have to do with this?

Comment: @aschepler In some terns you are right. That's neither a class type nor a non-class type. I'm deleting the first section of the answer, I'll leave there the alternative solutions anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't scale very well to a large `D`, but if you're just after the four to six variants I'm imagining, you could partial-specialize a base class:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, size_t D>
struct VectorBase;

template<typename T>
struct VectorBase<T, 2>
{
    constexpr VectorBase() : v{} {}
    union {
        T v[2];
        struct { T x, y; };
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct VectorBase<T, 3>
{
    constexpr VectorBase() : v{} {}
    union {
        T v[3];
        struct { T x, y, z; };
    };
};

template<typename T>
struct VectorBase<T, 4>
{
    constexpr VectorBase() : v{} {}
    union {
        T v[4];
        struct { T x, y, z, w; };
    };
};

template<typename T, size_t D>
struct Vector : public VectorBase<T, D>
{
    using VectorBase<T, D>::v;
    using size_type = decltype(D);
    using value_type = T;

    constexpr Vector() : VectorBase<T,D>{} {}
    constexpr Vector(T scalar) {
        std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), scalar);
    }

    constexpr T& operator[](size_type i) const noexcept { return v[i]; }
    constexpr const T& operator[](size_type i) noexcept { return v[i]; }

    constexpr size_type size() const noexcept { return D; }

    constexpr T* data() noexcept { return &v[0]; }
    constexpr const T* data() const noexcept { return &v[0]; }
};

template<typename T>
using Vector2 = Vector<T, 2>;
template<typename T>
using Vector3 = Vector<T, 3>;
template<typename T>
using Vector4 = Vector<T, 4>;

int main() {
    Vector3<int> v{1};

    std::cout << v[0] << ", " << v.z << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/T3QHoq